# scanf reads wrong because of using %d to read bool

Tags: c++, scanf

```
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
  int a;
  bool b;
  scanf("%d %d",&a, &b);
  printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
}
```

when I typed 123 and 1, and then the program outputed 0 and 1.

Could you please tell me why this happend and how scanf works?

Comment: Undefined behavior due to reading an int into a `bool` variable.

Comment: Which conversion letter is specified in the `scanf()` specification for reading `bool`?  You can't find it?  Maybe that's because there isn't one, so attempting to read a `bool` using `%d` leads to problems — undefined behaviour problems.  `%d` expects an `int *` argument.  So, maybe you need to use `int c;` and read the value into `c` and then assign `c` to `b`?  Or maybe you shouldn't use `scanf()` in C++?

Comment: Your compiler didn't [warn you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a2be87d4b8edc6c)?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `&b`, you are passing the wrong pointer type to the function. After that, the program is subject to undefined behavior.

Don't try to make sense of the program after that. It's pointless to do so. Anything can happen after your program executes code that causes undefined behavior.

Just an FYI. `scanf` does not support a format specifier to read into objects of type `bool`. You can read the values 0 and 1 into a variable of type `int` or `short` and then assign to the variable of type `bool` appropriately.

```
int a;
bool b;
int dummy;
scanf("%d %d", &a, &dummy);
b = (dummy == 1);
```

Better still, use the stream extraction operators with `std::cin`.

```
int a;
bool b;
std::cin >> a >> b;
```